# Drupal project set up in apache giving no responce and no erros

Tags: php, mysql, apache, drupal, drupal-7

I have an old **drupal** project that needs to be deployed in my system.

I got the code and set up project mysql DB and everything.

While opening the webapp in browser its not showing blank page.Not even returning any errors.

I did the same in another system, it worked well, so there is no issue with code.

I have same version of **PHP,Mysql ,Apache** like in running system.

Why its not running in my system.?

Here is my apache error log.

```
[Thu Dec 04 09:57:49 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 04 09:58:02 2014] [error] [client 10.90.90.109] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu Dec 04 09:58:03 2014] [error] [client 10.90.90.109] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
[Thu Dec 04 10:11:36 2014] [error] [client 10.90.90.193] Directory index forbidden by Options directive: /var/www/myapp/main/, referer: http://10.90.90.109/careernetwork/
[Thu Dec 04 14:30:45 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Dec 04 14:57:10 2014] [error] [client 10.90.90.193] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/myapp/main/sites/all/modules/own/link_creator/link_creator.module on line 242, referer: http://10.90.90.109/careernetwork/
[Thu Dec 04 14:57:46 2014] [error] [client 10.90.90.193] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/myapp/main/sites/all/modules/own/link_creator/link_creator.module on line 242, referer: http://10.90.90.109/careernetwork/
[Thu Dec 04 18:08:23 2014] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 05 09:13:45 2014] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.15 with Suhosin-Patch mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 05 09:15:10 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/myapp/main/sites/all/modules/own/link_creator/link_creator.module on line 242
[Fri Dec 05 09:23:08 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/myapp/main/sites/all/modules/own/link_creator/link_creator.module on line 242
[Fri Dec 05 09:23:10 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/myapp/main/sites/all/modules/own/link_creator/link_creator.module on line 242
```

Log is showing that it has some errors , but don't have any as it executed perfectly in another system.

Please help me to fix this, I don't know were there any dependencies involved in this project.

How can I check all required dependencies of my drupal project.

My errors in browser:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the error logs, the error is in the file

```
/var/www/myapp/main/sites/all/modules/own/link_creator/link_creator.module
```

on line `242`.

Open this `link_creator.module` and try to find out where you have put unnecessary `[`

Just go there and remove the error.

This is a custom module (Module developed by project developer team not by Drupal core/contributed team).

So, you need to fix it by debugging on your own machine.

Please do the error reporting on by:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);// THE ERROR WAS SEMICOLON NOT PLACED HERE
```

Also, please see the `phpinfo()` if your PHP version is less than `5.3`, it should be a cause.

Comment: I tried to remove tha `[` but after its showing error some other place , the same code ran on another machine, then how come its wrong with code..?

Comment: Your PHP version might be a problem. Please paste the defective code here of course, if its not confidential.

Comment: I think `views` module is included twice.